# How to enter cents in ext Js 4 number field?

Tags: extjs4

when  trying to enter 12.80 in my number field, the last 0 get disappeared. How can i display the number field??

Comment: Isn't it an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior. If you want a custom implementation, you have to work a round the `parseFloat`. Because that (native) function will strip trailing decimal zeros (and leading zeros).

```
e.g. parseFloat("00100.00100") results in 100.001
```

The only way around, is by overriding at least these two functions:

```
parseValue : function(value) {
   //provide own implementation
   console.log('parseValue', value);
   return value;
},
valueToRaw: function(value) {
   //provide own implementation
   console.log('valueToRaw', value);
   return value;
}
```

Here is the [source](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/source/Number3.html#Ext-form-field-Number-method-rawToValue)